# Working out an inequality in the proof of Ostrowski's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, inequality, field-theory, valuation-theory

I am trying to work out the (sketch of) proof of Ostrowski's Theorem (on classifying archimedean completely valued fields) in J.S. Milne's Algebraic Number Theory course notes (http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf, Remark 7.49, proof in footnote).

I will just recap the one spot I'm having trouble with:
At this stage we have got a field $K$ complete with respect to an archimedean absolute value $\lvert \, \rvert$, with $\mathbb C\subseteq K$ and the restriction of $\lvert \, \rvert$ to $\mathbb C$ is the usual absolute value. 
We have taken an $x \in K\setminus \mathbb C$ and established the following inequality for all $z\in \mathbb C $ and $n \in \mathbb N$: $$\lvert x^n-z^n \rvert\geq \lvert x -z \rvert \lvert x \rvert^{n-1} .$$ 
The author then says ''on choosing $\lvert z \rvert <1$ and letting $n \to \infty$, we find that $\lvert x\rvert \geq \lvert x-z\rvert$''.

Now, I've divided both sides of the inequality above with $\lvert x \rvert^{n-1} $ and found $$ \lvert x \rvert + \lvert z \rvert \lvert z/x \rvert^{n-1} \geq \lvert x-z \rvert . $$

And indeed, we get what we want in the limit $n \to \infty$, if $ \lvert z \rvert<  \lvert x \rvert$. But it is essential for the rest of the proof that we get this for all $\lvert z\rvert <1$.

Is there something I am missing here? I hope that I'm not overlooking something terribly obvious...

Comment: But how do you conclude that $\lvert x\rvert ^n \geq \lvert x-z\lvert \lvert x \rvert ^{n-1}$ (and for which $n$)? Try a proof by contradiction and assume $\lvert x \rvert ^n < \lvert x-z\lvert \lvert x \rvert ^{n-1}$ for all $n$. On the other hand I have $\lvert x\rvert ^n + \lvert z \rvert ^n \geq \lvert x-z\lvert \lvert x \rvert ^{n-1}$ and $\lvert z \rvert ^n$ does get arbitrarily small, yes, but I don't see how to derive a contradiction because the difference $\lvert x-z\lvert \lvert x \rvert ^{n-1}-\lvert x \rvert ^n$ might also get arbitrarily small.

Comment: Can't you just scale your $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert \ge 1$?

Comment: The rest of the proof wouldn't work then. In the last line of the proof, Milne says that we replace $x$ with $x-z$ and do the same work for $x-z$ in order to get $\lvert x-2z\rvert=\lvert x-z\rvert =\lvert x \rvert$. Proceeding like this, we get a contradiction to the archimedean property. If I have to rescale in every step, then I can't get the equation $\lvert x-nz \rvert = \lvert x \rvert $ for all $n$.

Comment: Why do you have to rescale at every step? Milne proves $\lvert x-z\rvert = \lvert x\rvert$ so in particular $\lvert x-z\rvert \ge 1$.

Comment: You are right, thank you! I've actually had the idea to rescale and posted it as an answer here yesterday, but then deleted it 10 minutes afterwards because of (wrongly) thinking it would ruin the rest of Milne's proof.

Comment: I think I will post this and other details of the proof that I've worked out as an answer, later this evening.

Comment: It seems like you don't even need to scale your $x$ if you just take $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert < \lvert x\rvert$.